# Scale an iframe and its content to fit the viewport

Tags: html, css, iframe, transform, scale

I'm trying to take a web app designed for digital signage purposes (at a specific resolution) and scale it up or down for use on other screens with different resolutions. The aspect ratios of these different screens are all the same, but the resolutions are different. Ideally I'd like to keep the original content unmodified and wrap it in a new page with an `iframe`. However I'm having trouble finding the right combination of CSS transforms to achieve this. The original web app is build using HTML/CSS/JS. The final product needs to be a self-contained HTML file, but only needs to work in Chrome and will be displayed fullscreen.

Comment: So, what is your question/problem? do you have any code? and fiddle?